# Play online live game against a friend with time odds

Tags: online-chess, time-control, websites, odds

Is there an online chess site or app that would allow me and a friend to play live games against each other with time odds?

I am somewhere around a low class D player. My friend is somewhere around a high class F player.  He consistently loses games against me.  I know that what little game I have falls apart under time pressure. So, to even things out a bit, I'd like to be able to play him under time odds.

There is a bonus for a free solution, but I'm very willing to look at subscriber sites/apps (extra bonus if it's an app and it works on iOS and Android).

Comment: you might like: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haptic.chesstime

Comment: Hi astuter, we are currently playing on Chess Time, and it's a good general platform for us, but I can't see anywhere where it allows different time settings for different players, and it seems to better support the idea of 'online correspondence chess' (i.e., long time controls of x days per move).

Comment: @nooblet I would like to say that all the answers here still work. So why would you say "except adding time manually on Lichess, since that's not an option" because the lichess answer does work. On a laptop you have to click the blue button with a plus. I think you turned off add time [look here more more info](https://lichess.org/forum/general-chess-discussion/adding-time-2).

Comment: @VarunW. I said that because, to me, clicking the button manually 20 times before each game is not a viable way to achieve time odds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On [Lichess](https://en.lichess.org) there is a button that allows you to give 15 seconds to your opponent. You could use it to just give a bunch of extra minutes to your friend at the start of a game.

Comment: lichess has an app; I can verify it works on iOS and I believe I've seen friends use it on Android.

Comment: BlindKungFuMaster -- oddly enough I found my own way to lichess.org from other posts here. Your suggestion might be the best solution, at least of anything I've found so far myself. Extra note: I can't believe I wasn't aware of the existence of lichess.org!

Comment: @Ghotir I can confirm that it works excellently on Android as well.

Comment: There is currently an [open issue on the lichess GitHub repository](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/issues/9814) for actually implementing this feature instead of manually giving 15 seconds to your opponent.

Answer (score 5):

On the ICC, you can specify a match request to include two pairs of time controls when you request a match with a specific opponent.

For example, you can enter the command:

match FIZZBANG 30 10 45 20

and you would get a SD 30 d/10 time allowance, while FIZZBANG would be playing at SD 45 d/20.